# Get document whenever there is a new document inserted in collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I developing application using mongodb and node js. I want to get document from collection using node js mongoose whenever a new document inserted in the collection(document inserted from python side).Currently, I have query which i run in time interval of 1 seconds using setInterval.

So, Is there any another efficient way without setinterval.

Comment: We don't know what you like to do, perhaps the `insertedId` field from [insertOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertOne/index.html) could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tailable cursors](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/tailable-cursors/) on mongodb's [oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-oplog)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this can be easily achieved by using [mongodb change streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/).

You can see more about here with code examples.

[power of mongodb change streams](https://medium.com/@montumodi/power-of-mongodb-change-streams-6e050ef3c499)

Basically listen for insert operation type and react accordingly. This is much efficient then tailing oplog.

Comment: You are absolutely correct.It's only possible with replica set not for standalone database.